# how to bring data from an RDD using row values in other RDD

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql

we are trying to bring the data from the RDD based on the rows in other RDD.
for example.we have 2 tables with master and transaction data.transaction data has large volumes of sales data, so we like to get sales data only for specific customer and region values,do calculations and save it has file.
table1-CustomerID, regionID
table 2-RegionID,CustomerID,sales,product ID.

Please suggest

Comment: What is there in your master and transaction table? any sample?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to join the two `RDD`'s to one with the `.join` function.

For more see..
http://apachesparkbook.blogspot.com.au/2015/12/join-leftouterjoin-rightouterjoin.html

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply, I don't want to join, I like to get the data from the sales table , specific for customer and region  and save it has file.